# Can a discord.py bot not be case sensitive?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot right now, and it won't respond if I use capitals/don't use capitals. Is there a way for a bot to detect messages even if they're capital/lowercase? Is there also a way for a bot to be able to do the same with spaces (if I accidentally forget to put a space, or accidentally merge two words together...)?

Or do I have to make an endless trail of if statements?

Comment: Are you using bot.commands or on_message?

Comment: on_message is what Im usin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you get your message in the `msg` variable, then if you use `msg.lower()` you'll get the lowercase version of the response and you can check on that to see what the command was.

also, running `msg.replace(' ', '')` would create a value where all spaces are removed, and you can check the corresponding value of this variable instead of the original one.

for example:

```
msg = 'HeLlO wOrLd'
print(msg.lower().replace(' ', ''))
>> helloworld
```

assuming this is a command line interface, I truly suggest you follow the guidelines in the builtin argparse library.

see here: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html

Answer (score 2):

Below is example code of how to achieve this.

```
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('client ready')

@client.command()
async def ping():
    await client.say('Pong')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    message.content = message.content.lower().replace(' ', '')
    await client.process_commands(message)

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Note how `message.content` is replaced with `message.content.lower().replace(' ', '')`. Since the `ping` command is in lower case, this means that when a user types for example `!PinG`, the command will still be executed.

You should be careful of removing spaces though, as some commands that you might create in the future can take parameters as inputs, in which case you need spaces when calling the command to separate the parameters.

Comment: See this answer for a different approach within `discord.py` https://stackoverflow.com/a/50548698/9083371