# Command Case Insensitve

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How to make below command to work if members use below command in lower or upper or mixing.
If members use `ping`  it works.
but if members use `Ping` it not works.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    message.content = message.content.lower()
    await bot.process_commands(message)

    @bot.command(pass_context=True)
    async def ping(ctx):
        msg = 'Pong {0.author.mention}'.format(ctx.message)
        await bot.say(msg)
```

Update:

above `on_message` is working correctly in single file but i splitted main file to multiple files. now how to make it work for cog in all files.

Comment: reply got deleted ?

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50359600/can-a-discord-py-bot-not-be-case-sensitive

Comment: @Benjin Super bro its really working Thank you...  but i have another problem `async def ping(ctx):`  works but how do i make it work for `async def mobile phones(ctx):`  . there is a space between `mobile phones`  we need that space.

Comment: I'd suggest editing this question or creating a new one to include your new case. But in short, it should be possible with the `on_message` event.

Comment: @Benjin Ok for above code how to add return message for wrong commands. For example: If anyone type `ping` it replies with `Pong` but if anyone type `pinng` or any wrong commands it generates error in bash but still it keep running script. So what i need is if anyone types wrong commands they should get a message in same channel `Please use correct command`

Comment: @Demotry See the documentation section on [error handling](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a [`case_insensitive`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.case_insensitive) option to your `Bot` when you create it.

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot('!', case_insensitive=True)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    msg = 'Pong {0.author.mention}'.format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
```

Comment: hello Patrick this one not worked for me. `@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    message.content = message.content.lower()
    await bot.process_commands(message)` this works in single file but how to make it work for cog in all files.

Comment: Remove the decorator, change the signature to `on_message(self, message)` and change `bot` to `self.bot`

Comment: yes i tried that before it works. but i get multiple reply if used commands. if i add `on_message` in all cogs file.

Comment: If you have many `on_message` events across multiple cogs, then all of those `on_message` events will be triggered.  That means that potentially many `process_commands` are being called for a single message.

Comment: no i have only 1 `on_message` this one `async def on_message(message):
    message.content = message.content.lower()
    await bot.process_commands(message)`  but do i need to add this in every file. i splitted main file to multiple files.

Comment: No.  Though you split your logic across multiple files, you load all of those cogs into a single bot.  You don't need to duplicate any of the code.

Comment: Oh shit i'm really a fool i never thinked this i added that code in all cogs.  now removed that code in all cogs only added in main file. now its working perfect thank you.